# Apex: I'm shoving all the DML into a queued job, but still get "Uncommited work pending"

Tags: apex, dml, queueable-apex

So, I've heard that you cannot do any Callouts after a DML operation in Apex. So, I've designed my app this way (some pseudo-code follows):

```java
String url;
List<Object> chunk;

for (Integer page=1; page<10; page++) {

    url = '/responses?per_page=' + PER_PAGE + '&page=' + page;

    // Callout happens inside client.get():
    chunk = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(client.get(url));

    // all DML is in here
    ProcessRecordsJob processJob = new ProcessRecordsJob(chunk);
    System.enqueueJob(processJob);
}
```

From what I know, a queued job must have an isolated execution context. So, why do I get "Uncommitted work pending"?

Note: it's not in the test (there is not real isolation in tests, but that's different issue); it works this way on the prod…

Note 2: I can see in the logs that the error happens after it tries to execute "page=2" (i.e. second) callout request.

Could the `System.enqueueJob()` itself produce that DML, after which I can't do no more callouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, doing pretty much anything with the database will cause this exception to be thrown. This includes scheduling jobs, using queueable or batchable, sending emails, performing normal DML operations, and so on. You'll have to move the `System.enqueueJob` call outside the loop.

Comment: Ok, i've redesigned it a bit:

`public with sharing class SyncResponses implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts { public void syncIt() { url = '/responses?page=' + this.page; .. some checks that next page is possible ..; System.enqueueJob(new SyncResponses(this.page+1); }}`

Now I get `System.AsyncException: Maximum stack depth has been reached.` when trying to test is… After the third page.

Comment: I mean, there's no loop now, just enqueuing the same class with the next page number in the arguments

Comment: @pilat That's a Developer/Sandbox limitation. In production, you wouldn't encounter that error.